# Where should ruby gems live on a shared host account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, shared-hosting

I have an app running on my localhost which I want to install on my hosting account. The host is Bluehost and they appear to support RoR, as evidenced by [this tutorial](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/rails) which I am trying to follow precisely.

The thing I'm stuck on is where my ruby gems should be? I'm currently unable to `bundle install` even immediately after `gem install bundler` so I'm pretty sure my app is looking in the wrong place. But before I can correct that, I think I need to know what is the *right* place.

Currently it appears there are gems here:
~/ruby/gems/gems

This is my app's /config/environment.rb file:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Goodwatching::Application.initialize!

ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home5/secretde/ruby/gems/gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
```

Currently I can install a gem like this `gem install bundler` and it succeeds. But then afterwards I try `bundle install` and it says to intall bundler first.

Answer (score 0):

The `bundle install`fail means that you are unable to find the path to bundle executable.

Your PATH must to include the path to `bundle` executable.

You could tray something like `~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler/bin/bundle install` to workaround the path problem.

Comment: Thanks. If that's the work around, what's the "right" way to do it?

Comment: You should add a symlink to bundle in your path. With `echo $PATH`you will have the paths where the execs should live. Try to create a symlink with `ln -s ~/ruby/gems/gems/bundler/bin/bundle ~/bin/bundle` if ~/bin exists in your path. Then you should be able to call `bundle install` directly.